# System not working after adding new table in database using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Hi I am using webAPI in my asp.net mvc 5 app. initially my app was working fine when there were only currency and user inputs, but when I added new table in database (i.e. `Companies` and `CompanyCurrencies`) with `primary & FK relations` it is throwing an exception as below:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition.

The error is coming when I return data from `Data Access Layer` to the `middle layer` as follows:

```
private DataAccessLayer db = new DataAccessLayer();
public List<Currency> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Currencies.ToList<Currency>();
    }
```

`Data access layer` where I have linked my business object to db tables is as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().ToTable("Currency");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Companies");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyCurrency>().ToTable("CompanyCurrencies");
    }

    public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyCurrency> CompanyCurrencies { get; set; }
```

Models:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long CompanyCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CompanyCurrency
{
    [Key]
    public long RecordNo { get; set; }
    public long CompanyCode { get; set; }      //I have made it FK in db

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}$")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }   //and this one also

    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}$")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }

    public string MajorUnit { get; set; }

    public string MinorUnit { get; set; }
}
```

> What I think regarding the problem is that I have created new tables
>   with primary and foreign key relations and there would be some way of
>   defining these relations in EF but I don't know exactly what the
>   problem is? Its just my guess.

so anyone can help me regarding this would be a great help for me.
Thanks in advance

Here are the full details of the error;

**System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079**

> Message=The navigation property `CurrencyCode` is not a declared
>   property on type `CompanyCurrency`. Verify that it has not been
>   explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation
>   property.Source=EntityFramework

**StackTrace:**

```
    at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureAssociations(EntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntities(EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at eGLVersion1._0.Data.CurrencyProvider.GetAll() in d:\Laptop Backup\Proglib\eGLVersion1.0\eGLVersion1.0.Data\Providers\CurrencyProvider.cs:line 26
       at eGLVersion1._0.Web.Controllers.CurrencyWebAPIController.Get() in d:\Laptop Backup\Proglib\eGLVersion1.0\eGLVersion1.0.Web\Controllers\CurrencyWebAPIController.cs:line 31
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you check if there's an inner exception within EntityCommandExecutionException? Maybe it can give you more info about the problem

Comment: When I click "Get help for the inner exception", it takes me to this link which goes over my head... https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHSql);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true this is the link

Comment: What is in the Message Property?

Comment: Have you remembered to declare the virtuals in your classes [Relationship mapping in EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: How do I check the message property??

Comment: @bilpor no, I do not have declared virtuals, how do i do that??

Comment: thanks for the link bilpor, I think it will help.

Comment: The inner exception should contain a message that points you to the actual error. This often happens when you are selecting a column that does not exists in the database. This indicates that your migration didn't actually got executed in your database.

Comment: the inner exception shows this message:

The exception that is thrown when SQL Server returns a warning or error. This class cannot be inherited.
Namespace:   System.Data.SqlClient
Assembly:  System.Data (in System.Data.dll)

Inheritance Hierarchy
System.Object
  System.Exception
    System.SystemException
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
        System.Data.Common.DbException
          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right that the exception is relating to some of the relationships not been defined. you can define relationships via Attribute on your properties in you classes or using the Fluent Api in OnModelCreating like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){

 modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyCurrency>()
                    .HasForeignKey(companyCurrency => companyCurrency .companyId);

}
```

Please note, I have only typed in psuedo code to point in right direction. for more information have a look at [Relationships and navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564)
and [EF Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620)

EDIT: Sorry @UzairAshraf my bad, if you are usning Ef 6 or above use HasRequired and HasOptional. And since you are using Attribute, even more simple do this in your model classes by defining a virtual property.

```
'public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long CompanyCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    ...
}'

 public class CompanyCurrency
    {
        [Key]
        public long RecordNo { get; set; }
        public long CompanyCode { get; set; }      //I have made it FK in db
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}$")]
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }   //and this one also

        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    }
```

this will generate tables as

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.CompanyCurrencies",
                c => new
                    {
                        RecordNo = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        CompanyCode = c.Long(nullable: false),
                        CurrencyCode = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 3),
                        IsDefault = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.RecordNo)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Companies", t => t.CompanyCode, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.CompanyCode);
```

Comment: HasForeignKey is not coming in intellisense.

Comment: and also not giving option to import class too.

Comment: No still the same error. I used;

    modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyCurrency>().
                ToTable("CompanyCurrencies").
                HasRequired(x => x.CurrencyCode);

Comment: @UzairAshraf can you give us the full error details please

Comment: I have updated the question plz read the error details and help me, I am still unable to resolve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @UzairAshraf have you done the foreign key for currency code as well. like in the code 'public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }   //and this one also' then Public Currency Currency {get; set}